# how to use require in main.js

Tags: node.js, axios, browserify, require

I try to use axios in my main.js.
i tried import axios from 'axios'. ... I got error for import. I read here that I should use require instead of import. 
after that I tried

```
 var axios=require('axios');
```

but I got the error ....require is not defined.

after that I read about browserify. I installed it

```
npm install -g browserify
```

after that I used this code to bundle it

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

and I add this script to my index.html code.

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

but I got the same error

REQUIRE IS NOT DEFINED!!
I am actually confused. can somebody HELP ME!

appreciated

Comment: I did the same thing as you did and it's working fine for me. I tried it both with a global browserify install, as you did, and with a local one, as @Shireesha suggests. Browserify bundles create a `require` function at the very start of the script. Does your `bundle.js` starts with some sort of `require` definition? (code is obscure and without spaces so it is difficult to spot). I believe somehow your `bundle.js` is malformed. OR you're using `require` in another script that you're loading into the HTML page BEFORE the bundle.

Comment: thank you for your time. ja, it starts with require. shall I change anything with the main.js or it remains intact?
still the same ERROR

Comment: You are not intended to change bundle files manually at all, in order for them to work. However, maybe it helps if you toss some `console.log` calls in the `bundle.js` file, to check wether the error comes after the `bundle.js` start or before. On top of that: are you loading more javaScript files into the HTML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `require()` is not a valid function in client side Javascript and is primarily used in server side Node.js. I recommend you look into [require.js](https://requirejs.org/) as this does extend the client side to provide you with that function. Or else go with ES6 `import`.

Answer (score -1):

npm install axios --save-dev

will help you to solve problem